# R for data science exercise 5.5.2 question 1

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr

I am solving an exercise in "R for data science. An exercise under "useful creations functions" in the chapter data transformation with dplyr. The question goes as follows using the nycflights13 dataset:

Currently dep_time and sched_time are convenient to look at, but hard to compute with because they are not really continuous numbers. Convert them to a more convenient representation of numbers of minutes since midnight.

And I saw this answer online:

> transmute(flights,
> dep_time_since_midnight = (dep_time %% 100) + ((dep_time %/% 100) * 60),
> sched_dep_time_since_midnight = (sched_dep_time %% 100) + ((sched_dep_time %/% 100) * 60)
> )

Please the question is I don't understand the conversion, this is somewhat of a mathematical problem than a coding problem. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%%` is read as "mod", and it gives you the remainder (e.g. 7 %% 3 = 1)

`%/%` is integer division (e.g. 7 %/% 3 = 2)

In working with `dep_time`:

`hour = dep_time %/% 100`

`minute = dep_time %% 100`

so, the above expression can be read as minutes + hour * 60

Comment: Thanks but my main question is where is whya are we dividing by 100

Comment: It's because of the way `dep_time` is formatted, it's HHMM, dividing by 100 using modular arithmetic effectively allows you to isolate the HH and the MM parts, e.g. 517 corresponds to 5:17pm, and dividing by 100 splits the 5 and the 17 at the 100th digit place

Comment: Thank you very much, I now understand much better

Comment: No worries, would you mind upvoting my answer so that this question can be tagged as resolved, with an accepted answer, thanks!

Comment: @latlio 517 corresponds to 5:17pm or 5:17 am?